# Laravel: How to store href id in the new variable and display or use in the input field?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I want To Store the current user $emp->id from href , and use in the input value as like in my code that is written below. Is is possible? or if possible then please help me? and if this Question is not a big problem so i am sorry for that in advance.

```
<a href="{{'/employee'}}?id={{$emp->id}}" type="button" name="user_id" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
Apply Attribute
</a>

<form action="{{'/rating'}}" method="post">

   {{csrf_field()}} 

   <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{store here current user}}">    

</form>
```

Comment: If you have the $emp variable passed through to your view, you can acces it just the same as you do in your href.

Comment: but we using foreach loop , and we want to get value after submission of form

Comment: and if we use this same in the value they all of the time give me the user id of 1

Comment: thats why we want to store after click and then use it in the form of value . thanks sir

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: but your href implies that you have $emp defined and passed through..You need to look at your route and controller and pass the $emp->id through via binding perhaps.

Comment: yes i am already define and getting all the user details with id , like that  @foreach($employ as $emp)
                                <tr> 
                                    <th scope="row">$emp->id</th> </tr> but here i am apply attribute to specific user

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Do you want to grab the id from the url and pass that through as $emp->id? Maybe show your specific route and controller and relevant view.

Comment: thanks brother i will try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Href Like That:

```
<a href="{{$emp->id}}" type="button"  id="uu_id" class="btn btn-primary uu" 
    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Apply Attribute </a>
```

Using This Script To get Value from Href:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".uu").click(function(event) {
            var u_id = $(this).attr('href');
            event.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById("hiddenVal").value = u_id;
        });

    });
</script>
```

And in your Form like this:

```
<form action="{{'/rating'}}" method="post">
 {{csrf_field()}} 

 <input type="submit"  style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="btn btn-success 
 pull-right" name="apply" value="Apply"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="hiddenVal" id="hiddenVal" />
</form>
```

And Last How to get this Value in the Controller And save to Database:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $rates = new Rating;
    $user_id = $_POST['hiddenVal'];
    $rates->user_id = $user_id;    
    $rates->save();
    return redirect('/employee');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you just need paste your current user inside INPUT:

```
<form action="{{'/rating'}}" method="post">

   {{csrf_field()}} 

    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ $emp->id }}">    

</form>
.....
```

Comment: I am already using this , but every time then will give me the user_id of 1 ,

Comment: why you using {{/employee}} is it a value? @Danish Butt

Comment: just in case you need get real user id: so you can get it via: `auth()->user()->id` from both twig and controller. Actually you can access it from anywhere in your application in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an id from a url you can :

```
Route::get('/url/{emp}', 'YourController@method');
```

In your controller:

```
public function method(Employee $emp) {
    //Your code
    return view('youre.view', compact('emp'))
}
```

Now in your view you have $emp and can acces id like $emp->id. 
Offcourse name it what you want but be sure to name it the same in your route,controller and view.

Now you don't need a forEach loop, because of the binding you already have the employee from the url

p.s: Employee model is just an assumption..name it whatever your model is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can use route function in blade for this.

Try this on web.php :

```
Route::get('/employee/{id}', 'YourController@YourMethod')->name('routename');
```

on your Controller your method need to have an arguments

```
public function YourMethod($id){
   // Code here
}
```

And on your blade make your href with route

```
<a href=" {{ route('routename', ['id' = $emp->id]) }}">Link</a>
```